# Can't limit cpu frequency Ubuntu 17.10, Acer Swift 3 (i5-8250)

Tags: cpu, frequency

I recently bought this laptop, I'm used to my limiting the CPU on my old one to avoid it getting too hot and extend battery when that's a priority over performance. However, `cpufrequtils` doesn't do anything.

I tried disabling `intel_pstate`, that results in the maximum frequency that I can set being 1.8MHz (instead of 3.4MHz). Even so `cpufrequtils` doesn't do anything. However writing to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` works.

After enabling `intel_pstate` again, I saw writing to `.../scaling_max_freq` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: try, for example, this: `echo "60" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct`. Your processor is very new, maybe the driver doesn't know about it yet.

Comment: Intel_pstate and cpufrequtils are an either/or prospect - they do not mix.  If you want ot use intel_pstate, you will use the cpupower commands, as in `sudo cpupower frequency-set -u 3.10GHz`

Comment: @CharlesGreen I forgot to mention that wasn't working either.

Comment: @DougSmythies This is great for what I need, it works. Thank you.